# Calculating the Big O of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I wrote the following code to reverse a String. How do I calculate Big O? This was an interview question for a junior developer position.

```
public static void reverseString(String str){

    String reversed = "";
    int lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");       
    while(lastIndex != -1){
        reversed += str.substring(lastIndex+1) + " ";
        str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
        lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
    }
    reversed += str;
    System.out.println(reversed);

}
```

Comment: Big O is the upper limit.. so in the worst case scenario the Big O will be the highest number of steps your loop executes.

Comment: This looks like it is Big-O(n) with n being the number of letters in the string.

Comment: If you show us how you attempted to solve the problem yourself, we will have some point of reference to base our answers/comments upon.

Comment: This is obviously a homework question.

Comment: Without using any additional data structures, this was the only solution I thought of. My guess was O(n) (avg, best, worst) for this code (along the lines of the answers here (how many indexOf() calls)) but I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: Ruslan: No this was an interview question

Comment: What is the cost of lastIndexOf, substring, and string concatenation? The answers to those 3 questions aren't clear-cut, but it's reasonable to expect this code will run in O(N^2) time. Use of StringBuilder (or a StringBuffer with the right initial length) is probably what your interviewer expected.

Answer (score -2):

O(n).  You go all the way down the length of the string, no matter what, via your call to `lastIndexOf`.